# Does cx_Oracle works with flask-python?

Tags: python, oracle, flask, cx-oracle

I'm wondering if cx_Oracle works with flask-python.

if so, please share with me a good documentation. it will be great.

Thank you All for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my blog post [How to use Python Flask with Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/how-to-use-python-flask-with-oracle-database) which has a runnable example.

The key thing is that during application initialization you will want to start a connection pool with `cx_Oracle.SessionPool()`.
Then each route can get a connection from the pool with `connection = pool.acquire()`

Also see https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/apaas/python/python-oracle-accs/python-oracle-accs.html, however this doesn't use a connection pool so it has some scalability limitations.